# JSON service data edit in Angular js

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, share, ionic-framework

What I actually want is that. I want to share my data with whatsapp. i managed to do it but the problem is that, when I send the  data it looks like this

```
"J&J Baby Cl Lemon Frsh 250ML,6, \n","J&J Baby Cl Lemon Frsh 250ML,6, \n","J&J Baby Cl Lemon Frsh 250ML,9, \n","J&J Baby Cl Lemon Frsh 250ML,4, \n","J&J Baby Cl Lemon Frsh 250ML,6, \n","J&J Baby Cl Lemon Frsh 250ML,5, \n"]
```

i want to send a list of items like this:

```
1)J&J Baby Cl Lemon Frsh 250ML [6]
2)J&J Baby Cl Lemon Frsh 250ML [4]
3)J&J Baby Cl Lemon Frsh 250ML [3]
4)J&J Baby Cl Lemon Frsh 250ML [8]
```

This is my **HTML**:

```
<ion-option-button class="button-calm"
 ng-click="share(item.id)">
         Share
</ion-option-button>
```

This is my **CODE:**

```
    $scope.share = function (listid) {
    $scope.detaillist = [];
    var db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "Bd_DB.db" });
    var query = "SELECT * FROM ListDetail WHERE listid= ?";
    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [listid]).then(function (res) {
        for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
            $scope.detaillist.push(res.rows.item(i));
        }

        var shareValue = [];

        for (i = 0 ; i < $scope.detaillist.length; i++) {
            shareValue.push($scope.detaillist[i].title + ',' + $scope.detaillist[i].quantity + ',')

        }
        alert(shareValue);

        $cordovaSocialSharing.share(shareValue)

           .then(function (result) {

               // Success!
           }, function (err) {
               alert(JSON.stringify("error" + err));
               // An error occurred. Show a message to the user
           });

     }, function (err) {
         return err;
        alert(JSON.stringify(err));
         console.error(err);
     });





  };
```